# Appending select box

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, append

I'm trying to add my select options into a select box when the user clicks an image. The image opens up a hidden search div containing the box. I have the following code:

html

```
<select id="search_state" name="state" class="large">

</select>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.search').click(function() {
    $('#search_state').append('<optgroup label="Chile"><option value="907">Región Metropolitan</option></optgroup><optgroup label="China"><option value="1355">Guangdong</option><option value="1353">Hainan</option><option value="1341">Jiangsu</option><option value="1307">Shanghai</option></optgroup><optgroup label="Costa Rica"><option value="1037">Alajuela</option><option value="1041">Guanacaste</option><option value="1043">Heredia</option><option value="1047">Puntarenas</option><option value="1049">San José</option></optgroup>');
    alert("works");
  });

});
```

The image class is .search, and the selectbox ID is #search_state. For some reason I can't get the selectbox to append, but the alert works onclick. Even when the box is hidden, its still listed under the source code. Does anyone know why I'm having this issue?

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3RC5k/1/

Comment: Your right.. Hmm.. Could it have something to do with using dropkick to style the selectbox?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715358/how-to-reload-jquery-dropkick-object

Comment: or see https://github.com/Robdel12/DropKick/pull/114

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is using `dropkick`then call refresh method after changing the select programatically

```
$('#search_state').dropkick('refresh')
```

Comment: Guess all I had to do was call a refresh, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

could you try to fill selectes content istead of appending

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $('.search').click(function() {
        $('#search_state').html('<optgroup label="Chile"><option value="907">Región Metropolitan</option></optgroup><optgroup label="China"><option value="1355">Guangdong</option><option value="1353">Hainan</option><option value="1341">Jiangsu</option><option value="1307">Shanghai</option></optgroup><optgroup label="Costa Rica"><option value="1037">Alajuela</option><option value="1041">Guanacaste</option><option value="1043">Heredia</option><option value="1047">Puntarenas</option><option value="1049">San José</option></optgroup>');
        alert("works");
      });

    });
```

Comment: If the `select` is empty, there shouldn't be a difference.

Comment: Still no luck, it might be something with the dropkick plugin I'm using